# How to read JMP *.jmp file with Python Pandas into Pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, csv, dataframe, sas, sas-jmp

I am struggling to read [SAS JMP files](https://www.reviversoft.com/file-extensions/jmp) with Pandas `read_csv` function into Pandas dataframe.  Does anyone have experience with this type of data file? What is the most efficient way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has worked for me. Its results are sometimes a bit unexpected (for example, sometimes I get CSVs without headers, even though in JMP they have them).
Unfortunately, you need to have SAS JMP installed and this solution only works on Windows.

```
import pandas as pd
from win32com.client import Dispatch

jmp = Dispatch("JMP.Application")
doc = jmp.OpenDocument('sasjmpfile.jmp')
doc.SaveAs('sasjmpfile.csv')

df = pd.read_csv('sasjmpfile.csv')
```

Comment: Thank you, Seems to be working. Making work much easier. Appreciate help and sorry for delayed response.