# Reading .jmp files with Python on a Mac

Tags: python, sas-jmp

Apparently `pandas.read_sas` can only read XPORT or SAS7BDAT format SAS files while `Dispatch` from `wind32com.client` can read .jmp format but only on windows. So is there a straightforward way to read in JMP files with Python on a Mac?

Comment: Have you seen this question [How to read JMP \*.jmp file with Python Pandas into Pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46476460/how-to-read-jmp-jmp-file-with-python-pandas-into-pandas-dataframe)?

Comment: That's a Windows only solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Feb 2019 it doesn't seem possible to read in .jmp files using Python on a Mac. The best option is probably to get a 30-day trial of JMP software and convert .jmp files to csv or something from there. You can also read SAS files (not .jmp) in R with haven::read_sas().