# Opening JMP file without JMP

Tags: python, r, excel, file, sas-jmp

My JMP license has run out and unfortunately I can no longer use JMP (not even the free version). I have JMP files that I want to open. How can this be done without JMP? Is there a way to do this using Excel? Python? R? Any software?

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46476460/how-to-read-jmp-jmp-file-with-python-pandas-into-pandas-dataframe Best,
Stefano

Answer (score 0):

JMP JSL files are not binary files and can be read with notepad++. JMP data table files are in a proprietary binary data format and cannot be read by other programs. I would reach out to the JMP company directly (jmp.com) and they may be able to help you. If you read a .jmp file with notepad++, you can see human readable text of attached scripts in the table but not the data unfortunately.